# Git commit, push and pull with Gnome-Builder

Tags: gnome, gnome-builder

How to do git commit, push and pull in builder?
I have not found any way to graphically do this through the IDE Builder.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible yet. There is a [feature request](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-builder/issues/635), and the [Roadmap](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Builder/Roadmap) mentions the "Git Perspective":

> We would like an additional “Git” perspective that can be used to
>   manage various source control aspects. You might use this to stage
>   files for commit. You might use it to browse your projects history
>   including searching for a previous commit to inspect it.

Answer (score 0):

git GUI might help you or you have comes in the terminal no choice.